# Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: file:///C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/navigator.dart:4532:12

Tags: flutter, dart, web, web-frontend

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './interview.dart';
import './profilepage.dart';
import './googlesignup.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  HomePage(
      {super.key, required this.mailId, required this.name, required this.pic});

  String mailId;
  String name;
  String pic = "";



  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Home page"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
        actions: [
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop(
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) =>
                        ProfilePage("data:imJy+r2EKkN2l65xhRjrODuDOGSOX76eNM+9T5rwYd+OOOyAR0vA6w6+gjEQiUr+bqpnJ/uGmjaRdZFh40GKjdvH1pau8C0saW81R0lAty9idmf0CrPXpzp6gr11ZILJOuAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==",mailID: mailId, name: name, img: pic)),
                        

              );

              //ProfilePage(mailID: mailId, name: name, img: pic);
            }, 
            child: CircleAvatar(
              radius: 30,
              backgroundImage: NetworkImage(pic),
                 // "https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/442/477/png-clipart-computer-icons-user-profile-avatar-profile-heroes-profile.png"),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            const DefaultTextStyle(
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.amber,
                  fontSize: 40,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              child: Text('Welcome to the interview'),
            ),
            //
            const SizedBox(height: 30,),
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).push(
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => Interviewimg(
                          isL2Locked: false,
                          isL3Locked: false,
                          isL4Locked: false,
                          2),
                    ),
                  );
                },
                child: const Text("Click to Take Interview")),
                const SizedBox(height: 20,),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.amber,
                  child: InkWell(onTap: (){},
                  child:TextButton(onPressed: () {
                    print("working");},
                    child: Text("TEST"),),),
                )

          ],
        ),
      ),
      
    );
  }
}
```

If I trying to navigate from this page next page it is not allowing me to navigate & the error is logging. I gave to page navigation in this code either of these are not working. Previously it is working while i was working on this page alone but while I am connecting the pages it ends up showing errors. I

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided is mostly correct, but there are a few issues.
In the **GestureDetector** onTap method, you are popping the current page and then pushing a new one. This might not be the behavior you want. If you want to navigate to a new page, you should just use `Navigator.push` or `Navigator.pop` without any arguments.

The **ElevatedButton** onPressed method pushes a new `Interviewimg` page. However, the `Interviewimg` constructor is called with a number (2) as the last argument, but it's not clear what this number is supposed to represent.

I will provide you the correct code.

```
  GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
      Navigator.of(context).push(
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => ProfilePage(mailId: mailId, name: name, img: pic),
        ),
      );
    },
    child: CircleAvatar(
      radius: 30,
      backgroundImage: NetworkImage(pic),
    ),
  )
```